# Marshal.PtrToStructure() that struct contains a double pointer menebre (mapped to IntPtr)

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, intptr

I am dymanically loading a win32 DLL and calling a function. The function contains a passing-by-ref parameter and the parameter is a struct contains a double pointer as a member. I marshaled the double pointer member as IntPtr, then marshaled the struct parameter as an IntPtr also. This part of the code seems have no problem.

After the function call (`MethodInfo.Invoke()`), I use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to get returned struct data from IntPtr and get exception `"Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized."`. I made sure the "Optimize code" is unchecked for the project.

The following is the simplified code:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int** xx;
}Struct_DoubPtr
int PassOutDoubPtrStructMember(Struct_DoubPtr* ptrStructMember);
```

marshal struct to IntPtr:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Struct_DoubPtr"));
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));
```

The "obj" is initialized with member x = 20 and xx = IntPtr before calling Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);

Marshal IntPtr to struct:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Struct_DoubPtr");
var newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
{   
    //if the field is an IntPtr 
    //a seperate function iscalled here to determine if the memeber is a IntPtr
    {   
        field.SetValue(newObj, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
Marshal.PtrToStructure(dataPtr, newObj); 
//where dataPtr is the strcut parameter from invoking PassOutDoubPtrStructMembe()
```

Any comments/suggestion will be a greate help.

Comment: Do you have both solution and project set to Debug configuration?

Comment: Yes, both are in debug mode.